# How to schedule a future repeating alarm in Android AlarmManager?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I was able to set a repeating alarm in Android using the following code. However, the issue is that it makes immediate notifications as well and I do not want that. I just want the user to put in the time they want the alarm to go off at and have the alarm go off at that time and repeat at the given interval that was chosen. I tried switching ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP instead of RTC_WAKEUP however that code did not work for me.

```
public static long getTimeForNotification(int hour, int minutes, int am_pm){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, am_pm);
    return  calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}

public static PendingIntent createNotificationPendingIntent(
        String name,
        String number,
        String messageArrayListString,
        String contactID,
        String photo_uri,
        String actionType,
        Context mContext
        ){

    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(mContext, AlertReceiver.class);
    alertIntent.putExtra("name", name);
    alertIntent.putExtra("number", number);
    alertIntent.putExtra("messageList", messageArrayListString);
    alertIntent.putExtra("contactID", contactID.toString());
    alertIntent.putExtra("photo_uri", photo_uri);
    alertIntent.setAction(actionType);


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, Integer.parseInt(contactID.toString()), alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    return pendingIntent;
}

public static void createNotifications(PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent, Context mContext, Long alarmTime, int frequencyMultiplier){

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * Long.valueOf(frequencyMultiplier), notificationPendingIntent);

}
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use.

```
public class AlarmHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "AlarmHelper";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12377;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_OVERTIME = 12376;

    private AlarmHelper() {
    }

    public static void scheduleAlarm(Context c) {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, REQUEST_CODE, new Intent(c, ClockInBroadcastReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


        //Set next clock-in time
        GregorianCalendar time = new GregorianCalendar();
        time.add(...,...); //Whatever you want to add.


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis() + 1000, pendingIntent);
        } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis() + 1000, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis() + 1000, pendingIntent);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Did this help you?